# How to create many different objects from one class in Java

Tags: java, class, object, arraylist

I want to create a program in Java that is essentially a book library. I am planning on having a constructor for the class which will take in some parameters. The problem I have is with how I am going to store every single book (I am not very experienced so I may be going about this the wrong way). What I was thinking was that I would have an `ArrayList` which would hold `Book` objects. The problem here is how can I make hundreds of objects from the book class with different names. Alternatively, if I am going about this completely the wrong way how should I be storing the books in a list?

Comment: If you are using an `ArrayList`, the objects won't have names. Objects in an `ArrayList` are indexed instead, starting at `0`.

Comment: @Logan yeah but the problem is the fact that I need to make a new object of type Book for every book in my library and I want to store each object. But is there any way to make many different objects non manually. For example say the first object is Book b = new Book(); how do I make say a hundred of those with different names.

Comment: Just because you create an object does not mean it needs to be stored in a named variable. You could do something like `books.add(new Book("JCiP", "Brian Goetz"));`

Comment: @Logan awesome thank you so much for clearing that up.

Comment: You could store the books in a text or XML file, or in a database, and then load them into memory that way.

Comment: @EJoshuaS yeah I was gonna store names in a file, authors in a file, and publication in another

Comment: Yes, I think that you probably want to do something like that (i.e. store them externally rather than trying to hardcode them all in code) - that way you don't have to recompile your program every time you want to change the data.

Comment: Don't separate the data for individual books-unless you're planning on using something like an author index like how a relationship database would work. Not sure why you're not using a database.

Comment: @DaveNewton to be honest I really dont know have to and have not used one before. Do you reccomend any resources for me to learn one?

Comment: @gamerage3 Nope. But there are tons of tutorials/etc. from which to start piecing things together. I'm not saying you *must* use a DB, I'm just saying that keeping track of data is kind of what they're used for. You *can* keep data in any number of file formats, but it's almost never the best approach.